# Which one of these three forms of "Offer" should I use? "I offer ___", "I am offering ___" or "Offering ___"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I want to express in my bio (Instagram, Twitter etc.) that I do and sell these services:

> Digital marketing, Protection of privacy and personal information on the internet and social media, Speed-up and repair of slow computers

**From both grammatical and practical way, which one of these sentences should I use?**

First:

> I offer: Digital marketing, Protection of privacy and personal information on the internet and social media, Speed-up and repair of slow computers"

Second:

> I am offering: Digital marketing, Protection of privacy and personal information on the internet and social media, Speed-up and repair of slow computers

Third:

> Offering: Digital marketing, Protection of privacy and personal information on the internet and social media, Speed-up and repair of slow computers

To put it even more into the context, let's take the example of the whole potential bio:

> I am into meditation, philosophy, psychology, photography, veganism.
>
> (One of the sentences above)
>
> PM me or e-mail me for more details.
>
> Hi@example.com

Comment: I am thinking of using "Offering". It can be both noun and verb. As a noun it makes sense "Offering: ___" and if it's going to be in my bio then people will probably understand that I am the one offering those services thus it can also work as a verb (with omitting the "I am"). What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with *I offer:*, for two reasons.

1) *Offering* as a noun has another meaning quite unrelated to your context (a religious offering).

2) Although it does occur, dropping the subject is not particularly idiomatic in English.

Comment: Hi Evene, thank you for your answer. I decided to use "Offering" for social media because of it's flow and easier/faster readability and "I offer" for my website.